# Does magic resistance decrease the power of bound weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, giants have 33% resistance to magic. I just want to know if my bound bow would do 33% less damage to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bound weapons do not inflict magical damage.

Conjuring a weapon using Bound  Spell produces a magical weapon (equivalent to its Daedric counterpart in terms of stats), which inflicts normal damage. Thus the magic resistance of your target plays no role in how damage is calculated.

Just a couple  of aside notes:

- You can poison a conjured weapon;
- Bound weapon (total) damage takes into account your Conjuration Skill as well as your Weapon Skill (bow, one-hander, etc). As such, a basic Conjured weapon is potentially more deadly than its normal counterpart (before smithing & enchanting).